# How do I ensure my images/graphics are embedded in the output document?

Tags: graphics, pdf, lyx

I am new to LaTex and I am learning the concept and terminology by using Lyx (TeX live under Linux).

I created my first document using the `Book` class, added some images (combination of jpgs/pngs), and compiled to PDF. After sending the PDF to a Windows 7 PC and opening the PDF there the images where replaced by place holders and I got an error message.  It was searching for the images on the target computer. How do I ensure my images/graphics are *embedded* in the output document?

Comment: I doubt there is a way to **not** embedding images and graphics to the output document... Maybe have you use the `draft` option in your class declaration? Otherwise, you may also have not enough memory to see the picture on your second computer

Comment: @LionelMANSUY: Thanks, If i am understanding correctly you are saying the images should have been embedded on the output document but my mistake is that I may be using the "draft option".  I am assuming then that images don't show in the draft option.  FYI Memory is not an issue on either PC.

Comment: Hem... Draft option will speed the compilation and replace all picture by placeholder (white rectangle with black border) containing the picture name. So you should not have an error. I'm not soothsayer... your problem is probably related to YOUR error message...

Comment: @StephenMyall can you post a minimal example? see http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample